# Sharepoint Updates and Build Numbers

Tags: 2010, cumulative-update, build

I have two servers, one test and one production in which I ran the following command from Sharepoint Management Shell.

```
(get-spfarm).buildversion
```

I got two different build versions:

- 14.0.6117.5002 (test)
- 14.0.6120.5006 (prod)

However when I look on the list of most recent updates I see "Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2598151)" installed on both of these systems.

However on the test server I see "Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2598150)" as well which seems to correspond the build version it is giving me ( I don't see this on the prod server).

Can someone explain why this might happen and why my servers would be at different builds if they had the same updates installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hotfixes do not update core version numbers so even having the same hotfixes applied does not mean it is the same version.

According to the [SharePoint Build Numbers](http://blogs.technet.com/b/steve_chen/archive/2010/09/29/build-numbers-cube-sheet-for-sharepoint-2010.aspx), it your Test environment is on Feb 2012 CU while your Prod environment is on the Apr 2012 CU.  Having difference CUs applied in the various environments is never a good thing for development.  I would advise applying the Apr 2012 CU to all of your non-prod environments as soon as possible so that all development and testing is against the same core code that is running on production.

Comment: So you are saying I could have hotfixes for KB2598151 while still being at KB2598150? I was under the impression that these were actually the CUs am I wrong?

Comment: The fact that the versions are not reporting properly could also mean that the CU was not applied properly on your non-prod environments

Comment: [SharePoint 2010 build level and version numbers](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepointjoe/archive/2011/02/01/sp2010-sharepoint-2010-build-level-and-version-numbers.aspx), this one is more easy and helpful..

Comment: It looks cleaner but it is not updated recently